# Minimizing summation using Karush–Kuhn–Tucker

Tags: optimization, summation, nonlinear-optimization

Let $a_j, c_j , j=1,...n$ and b be positive constants. 
$$-$$
Minimize : $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{c_j}{x_j}$
 $$-$$
subject to:$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j =b$

$$-$$

Write down the kkt conditions and solve the resulting equations\begin{align}
  \\
 & f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{c_j}{x_j}  \\ 
 & h(x)= \sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j -b \\
 & \nabla f(x) = -\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{c_j}{x_j^2}  \\ 
 & \nabla h(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j
\end{align}
$\nabla L(x,v) = -\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{c_j}{x_j^2} + v*(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j ) = 0$

And we look for the cases when v = 0 and v is free? v could not be zero due to the fact that our x goes to infinity so x has to be < or > 0. 
My last step seems to be wrong, is the derivatives wrong? Thankful for any kind of hint or help.

Comment: You misunderstood KKT conditions.

Comment: @user295959 I wrote a bit wrong on my last step, what was wrong? Could you guide me maybe?